# SQL Self-Join Results Within Main Result (not seperate column)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Using: SQL Server 2012

I have a self-referencing table called `Department` like this:

```
DepartmentID | Name     | DepartmentParentID
1              Sales      NULL
2              Outbound   1
3              Inbound    1
4              Showroom   1
```

The departments such as `Inbound` and `Showroom` have a parent department of `Sales`.

I need to now write a SQL query that will show which users are in which departments. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName, d2.DepartmentParentID, d2.DepartmentName
FROM 
    [User_Department] ud ---table that maps users to departments
INNER JOIN 
    [Department] d1 ON d1.DepartmentID = ud.DepartmentID
LEFT JOIN
    [Department] d2 ON d2.DepartmentID = d1.DepartmentParentID ---this has gone horribly wrong
WHERE 
    ud.Username = @Username
```

Forgetting the LEFT JOIN part in the above code for now, I would get a result like this:

```
Username    |  DepartmentName
DannySmith     Inbound
DannySmith     Outbound
```

But what I need is the parent department to also show in the DepartmentName list **(this is what I want)**:

```
Username    |  DepartmentName
DannySmith     Sales
DannySmith     Inbound
DannySmith     Outbound
```

How is this possible to achieve. I don't want the parent department to be in a separate column like this (**this is what I DON'T want**):

```
Username    |  DepartmentName | DepartmentName
DannySmith     Inbound          Sales
DannySmith     Outbound         Sales
```

Been trying to look over some SQL books but can't find anything that can help me so far. Anyone please?

Comment: Which department `Dany Smith` is mapped to in your `User_Department` table ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the possibility of multiple levels of hierarchy, you should use a recursive common table expression. For example, if there could be child departments within Showroom, Inbound, or Outbound.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    ud.UserName, d.DepartmentID, d.Name, d.DepartmentParentID
  FROM 
    [User_Department] ud
  INNER JOIN 
    [Department] d ON d.DepartmentID = ud.DepartmentID
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    CTE.UserName, d.DepartmentID, d.Name, d.DepartmentParentID
  FROM
    [Department] d 
  INNER JOIN
    [CTE] on CTE.DepartmentParentId = d.DepartmentID
)
SELECT distinct UserName, DepartmentId, Name
FROM CTE
WHERE 
  Username = 'DannySmith'
```

If you know for certain that there is only one level of hierarchy, the answer that @sgeddes gave will work.

Comment: You are right, there could be multiple levels of hierarchy so this is a very good answer

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `UNION` (this also uses a common table expression which makes it a little easier to read):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
    ud.UserName, d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName, d.DepartmentParentID
  FROM 
    [User_Department] ud
  INNER JOIN 
    [Department] d ON d.DepartmentID = ud.DepartmentID
  WHERE 
    ud.Username = @Username
)
SELECT UserName, DepartmentId, DepartmentName
FROM CTE
UNION 
SELECT C.UserName, D.DepartmentId, D.DepartmentName
FROM Department D
  JOIN CTE C ON D.DepartmentId = C.DepartmentParentID
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dec9a/1)

BTW -- If I interpreted your table definitions correctly, your `UserName` field should probably be in its own `User` table.

Comment: Thank you sgeddes. My username is is another table for Users. This is just a joining table so it also has the Username in as a foreign key.